# hooking ADO.Net

Tags: ado.net, hook

I want to hook some functions when a process is using ADO.Net, what are the native function ADO.Net uses to connect to the database?
What Dlls does it use?

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET implementations use managed code to execute database operations. There is not single native function set that your are looking for.